# Normal Vector to Equitangular image workflow

Tags: image, vector, aframe, photoshop

I'm interested in converting a large vector graphic into an equitangular image. I'm looking to create an interactive 360 view in an AFrame project much like this one https://aframe.io/examples/showcase/sky/.

I've tried a plugin for photoshop called Flexify 2 but not having any luck. I'm open to different workflows or ideas on how to do this!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you explain the problems you've encountered? You say you tried something but it didn't work, what happened?

Comment: Try drawing the graphic on a `<canvas>` element. Then [using the canvas as texture](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/material.html#canvas-textures). Something like [this svg -> texture example](https://aframe-svgtocanvas.glitch.me/).